# IdentityServer4 personal access token (github-like) or API key for third party clients

Tags: authentication, openid-connect, identityserver4, api-key

Our current setup is

- IdentityServer4
- Angular + ASP.NET Core application
- Authentication for the app via implicit flow/oidc.

We want to provide APIs for customers, i.e. third party clients, with restricted access (separate set/subset of claims). These clients are mostly non-interactive scripts that download data.

This means that we cannot use any flow which (occasionally) requires user interaction. Personal access tokens, like in github, or some other *generate once, reuse for a long time* API key or token would be needed.

The long token lifetime would not be a security issue, because the token should only allow access to a few read-only APIs and only for that customer's data - so the responsibility to handle the token(s) falls onto the customer.

The customer should be able to create and revoke such API-access tokens based on their claims. Some users might only claims to access certain APIs.

*It would be good if we could later prevent that the user re-uses the same token for multiple clients because of licensing requirements but that is perhaps an entirely new question*

**How could I achieve this?**

I thought about doing this via a custom grant, similar to a *delegation grant*: user uses app, which calls the asp.net core API, which performs auth with that custom grant, persists that token somewhere (just a plain table in the database full of customer-api-only tokens? I'm not sure about that) and shows it to the user - which can also retrieve it later from storage.

I'm thinking about doing the "delegate"-authentication via our API so that we don't leak the secrets into the Angular application.

I think that we then should be able to have either long-lived access tokens or at least refresh tokens via that custom grant.

## 2017-12-12 how I think I could solve it

We want a process where the user generates *something* in our application (i.e. via our client) and this *something* can later be used by the user's third party client to access the API - or request an access token and then access the API.

We want this access to be tied to the user. This includes
 - Disabled user
 - Lockout
 - Specific claims (e.g. tenant)

This does not lend itself well to a solution that issues access tokens directly, because the token would remain valid even if the user was disabled or locked out. Which means that we cannot use a custom grant or `IdentityServerTools` to issue tokens directly.

Therefore we should use the client credentials grant, or something similar to it, as this could yield new, short-lived access tokens.

- User actually generates a new client, which is pre-filled with claims from  the user (such as the tenant - which is immutable) and has a claim that corresponds with the user. This happens transparently. Password should be user-supplied with the option to change it. We only store the relation between user and issued client-ids, no passwords.
- We have to create a custom grant, which works similar to client credentials, but also checks if the corresponding user is active etc. (which I think should be possible by injecting `UserManager`)
- Resulting access token lifetime is short, interaction with our APIs is expected to be short-lived.

Assuming it is safe and easy enough to write such a grant, we should be able to cover everything we need.
Of course, I might have completely overlooked something :)

Comment: You can use https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/topics/tools.html to manually generate tokens.

Comment: @leastprivilege oh, neat, I didn't know about that. It might not be of much use in our use case: ideally we would like users to create a token or client which is tied to their user account (for things like tenant, lockout etc.)

Generally, if we just issue long lived tokens, we won't have any control over how long the user's client can access the API subset.

Any ideas or pointers?

Comment: Hi @urbanhusky! I'm in the same situation as you. I see that this question was asked a long time ago, but can you say me what approach did you take if you can still remember it?

Comment: @Endri Sorry. We didn't implement a solution because we had other priorities and I went into burnout shortly thereafter and am no longer working at that company.

Comment: @Endri Did you have a look at this one?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63699424/identityserver4-using-apikey-or-basic-authentication-directly-to-api

Comment: Thank you @msr that seems interesting but I have choose not to use API keys and going through the use of `jwt` token.